# View not coming full screen in Android - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to show an ImageBackground as full screen, For that, I have given its parent and flex:1, so that it will cover the whole screen. It's working in iOS but not in Android. I'm not using SafeAreaView.

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

This is what I'm getting

[image]

Gist for the component can be found here https://gist.github.com/praveen-wal/79c495e58f54d5b8b7ace5f93d3bbff9

"react-native": "0.63.3"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the status bar translucent. It will make the app draw under the status bar on android. Then you can set the backgroundColor to transparent.

Links:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#translucent
https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#backgroundcolor

```
<StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
```